# unable to Upload photo on facebook wall in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, facebook, ios4, facebook-graph-api

In my iPhone app, I am trying to upload photo on facebook wall using [this code.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app)

It works fine when I am using in simulator, but when I try to upload from device it shows nothing on facebook wall.

EDIT: I am getting following error in console when running on device :

`sendToPhotosFinished` method :

```
Send To Photos Finished
ResponseString : {"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#1) An unknown error occurred"}}
ResponseJSON : {
             error =     {
             message = "(#1) An unknown error occurred";
             type = OAuthException;
             };
}
Photo id is: (null)
```

and in `getFacebookPhoto` method :

```
Got Facebook Photo: {"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: (null)"}}
```

While running in simulator I got all the values.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Does the function execute when running it on the device? Do you get empty posts, wall posts with no image?

Comment: I didnt get anything on wall post.

Comment: Well, if it works in the simulator and not on the device, it must be with the internet connection? does your facebook delegates/callbacks get notified at all? If its the exact same code, it must be something you are overlooking. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you pass the correct API key?

I think the problem is that you are not passing your API Key and hence it gives `null`.

That is where your problem lies.

http://www.insidefacebook.com/2010/11/17/api-test-user-developers/

Comment: @Anjali : Thanks for reply. If I provide incorrect API key, How can it work in simulator? It works fine in simulator. What can be wrong?

Comment: @Meghan: Sometimes things work well on simulator but fails on device

Comment: @Anjali : I am providing correct API key. What else should I check?

Comment: Can you send me your code? I will fix the bug and send back to you

Comment: Anyways it is up to u if you don't want to give the code. No bad intentions!!